I/0 error dev sda(root partition)
I've been trying to install windows on my brand new Western Digital ssd, no matter how i install, windows barely lasts 3 days before crashing and prompting a reinstall. This has happened over 8 times across 8 clean installs. It crashes at random intervals, mostly when installing or working in visual studio or sometimes when just idle.
I've decided to move to arch linux which has experienced many similar crashes prompting reinstalls as well. I've checked the journals and this seems to be the problem:
Jul 15 06:57:10 archlinux kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 13343536 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_>

Indicating the drive has gone through another corruption. Of course the most logical solution would be faulty drive right? I've also replaced the drive with another Western digital 1tb SSD. And the same thing keeps happening. I've ran memtest86+ for over 8 hours with no fails and over 6 passes. What could be the problem causing random bad blocks?

Most likely the drive, but faulty motherboard could also be the case. Do note that its not unheard of of getting a DoA harddisk (aka, a harddisk that is already faulty at the start) Luckily doesn't happen that often, but it happens. Make sure by testing with a 3rd harddisk.

Failure rate charts are "bathtub" shaped. As in, failure rates are highest when the product is new, then fall off to low levels through the middle of a product's age, and then begin rising again as the product reaches its normal end of life. Like others have said, the evidence suggests your drive is bad. As it is new, it is trivial to replace it at this time, so do that.

But what are the odds of purchasing and installing two faulty SSD's back to back? I've run a bios update now. I'm going to see how long it can last before turning it back in for an HDD again

Low, but not non-zero. I'd make sure the replacement drive is not from the same batch, for one, and then I'd begin replacing other components. You only note the SSD is new, indicating to us the other components have been "tested" by use for an extended period of time. But it IS possible another component is faulty.

Drive just locked on me again @music2myear. You were right. Will replace it with another brand other than western digital
